# How to preview multiple files on input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paperclip

I can select multiple files on `input logos` and I would like to preview all of it. For the moment I can only display one of those.

I don't know how to loop through each file using this code :

```html
     $(function() {
        $("input[name='cover[logos][]']").on('change', function(event) {
            var files = event.target.files;
            for(i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                var image = files[i]
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(file) {
                  var img = new Image();
                  img.src = file.target.result;
                  $('#target').html(img);
                  }
                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
             };
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try to append with `$('#target').append(img)` instead of replacing the content with `$('#target').html(img)`

Comment: Tip, use URL.createObjectURL instead of the fileReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$('#target').append(img);
```

instead

```
$('#target').html(img);
```

For replacing images when user change his input

```
$('#target').html('');
for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   //loop code
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fgeagtms/)

Comment: Thank you it works. But using this it doesn't replace images if the user change his input...

Answer (score 2):

your js is fine just change html to append

```
$('#target').append(img);
```

and use

```
$('#target').html('');
```

to clear previously chosen

Comment: Thank you it works. But using this it doesn't replace images if the user change his input...

Comment: add $('#target').html(''); at top of your change event